# How to use ssh-copy-id on a non-standard port

Tags: ssh

I'd like to use key-based authentication to login to one of my computers. It has sshd running on a port that is not the default of 22.
I want to use `ssh-copy-id` to add my key to the list of authorised keys. I tried to specify the port using `-p`, as for the ssh command itself. However I get really strange error messages then.

For example

```
user@box:~$ ssh-copy-id -p 57777 -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@192.168.1.111
Bad port 'umask 077; test -d ~/.ssh || mkdir ~/.ssh ; cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'

user@box:~$ ssh-copy-id '-p 57777' -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@192.168.1.111 
Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
ssh: Could not resolve hostname umask 077; test -d ~/.ssh || mkdir ~/.ssh ; cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys: Name or service not known
```

How can I make it work? (I know I can manually add the key to the authorized_keys file on the server. But I am lazy and definitely curious how to convince ssh-copy-id to do its job :) )

Answer (score 10):

Quoting was already a good idea but rather do it like this:

```
ssh-copy-id -i /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub '-p 57777 user@192.168.1.111'
```

Put everything you want to tell the ssh command the script uses at the end and quote all of that. The script expects the last argument to be the hostname and hence copies it at the end of its generated ssh command.

(Apparently this is a known issue. See [this bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=99785) and [this one](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=510932))

Comment: Oh, great! That works! Thanks. Strange though, that it did not get fixed in 10 years.

Comment: Probably it did not get a high priority as there is a workaround :S

Comment: @zpea nice! On an old Fedora here. You made my day easier

Answer (score 1):

For those that want a replacement script here is my `ssh-copy-id.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh $* 'mkdir -p ~/.ssh;echo '`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`' >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys;chmod 700 ~/.ssh;chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
```

Now you can just `ssh-copy-id.sh blah@stuff.com -p123456`

Obviously its not as fancy as the real one but at least it works for the logged in user.