# Copying an SSH ID to a server from a certain computer yields an error while the same command works fine from other computers

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, debian, terminal

I get the following error message when trying to copy an SSH key to a remote server:

```
ssh-copy-id -p*** ****@****.com

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

ssh: Could not resolve hostname umask 077; test -d ~/.ssh || mkdir     ~/.ssh ; cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && (test -x /sbin/restorec: Name or service not known
```

Changing the command to:

```
ssh-copy-id -T -p*** ****@****.com
```

Changes the error to:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname umask 077; test -d ~/.ssh || mkdir ~/.ssh ; cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys && (test -x /sbin/restorec: Name or service not known
```

This exact same command works fine from other computers on the network.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use ssh-copy-id on a non-standard port](http://superuser.com/questions/446665/how-to-use-ssh-copy-id-on-a-non-standard-port)

Answer (score 1):

Avoid the problem with using `-p` in (some versions of) `ssh-copy-id` by adding the host to your `~/.ssh_config` (where you will probably want it long-term anyway):

```
Host ****@****.com
Port ***
```

Now run `ssh-copy-id` without the `-p`argument:

```
$ ssh-copy-id ****@****.com
```